# Google Charts disable y-axis to the right

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

How do I disable y-axis to the right, so all columns will use y-axis to the left?

[image: Y-axis right]

Options code:

```
var options = {
   stacked: true,
   series: {
        2: { axis: 'counter1' }
   }
};
```

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/kn4hcjww/2](https://jsfiddle.net/kn4hcjww/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replying late but someone will find it usefull anyway.

Each series is pointing to targetAxisIndex. Axis index 0 is at left side of y-axis. Higher indexes are sided to right by default.

**Solution**

Config the targetAxisIndex to zero index.

```js
series: { 
  0: {
    targetAxisIndex: 0,
  },
  1: {
    targetAxisIndex: 0,
  },
};
```